# Estimating the number of divisors of a given number

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I developed an algorithm which runs in $O(n\cdot d)$ where $n$ is the number and $d$ is the number of divisors (not necessarily prime divisors) of that same number. I was wondering if there is any way to estimate the number $d$ based on $n$? I'm interested in worst case scenarios, and my hunch was that $d$ should be $o(\log(n))$ (notice that this is little $o$ notation because if $n$ is prime, then $d = 1$). Is there any way to prove or disprove this?

Comment: The worst case scenario is covered by the "highly composite numbers". Just google this.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate) [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function#Examples) wiki pages. For the worst case, we have for all $\varepsilon > 0$:
$$
d(n) = o(n^\varepsilon)
$$
and more presisely
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log d(n)}{{\log n}\ /\ {\log\log n}} = \log 2
\implies d(n) = e^{O\left(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\right)}
$$
However, the [average order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function) of $d(n)$ is $\log n$, meaning that
$$
\sum_{n\le x}d(n) \sim \sum_{n\le x}\log n
$$

For completion, for the "best" case we have $\liminf_{n\to\infty} d(n) = 2 = O(1)$ because of primes. So only in the best case is your guess $o(\log n)$ true.

Here is a simple proof that $d(n)=o(\log n)$  is false. Let $n_k = p_1\ldots p_k$ be the product of the first $k$ prime numbers. Then $d(n_k) = 2^k$ and by the prime number theorem
$$
n_k \le p_k^k \sim  (k\log k)^k 
$$
so in fact for for any powers $\alpha$ and $\beta>1$ we have
$$
\log^\alpha n_k = O(k\log k)^\alpha = o(2^{\beta k}) = o(d(n_k)^\beta)
$$